# Is a measure with non-negative value on open sets is non-negative measure?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

If a measure has non-negative measure value on open sets, then is it true that measure is non-negative?

Comment: What kind of measure do you have in mind? I.e. does it have any nice properties?

Comment: Basically I have that $\langle \mu,f\rangle\geq 0$ for $f\geq 0$ and $f\in C_b^1(U)$. Then I want to prove that $\mu$ is non-negative. Since there exists $\{f_n\}$ in $C_b^1(U)$ that converge monotonically to indicator functions on open sets I have $\mu(A)\geq 0$ for all open sets $A$. I want to prove that $\mu(B)\geq 0$ for all borel sets $B$.

Answer (score 0):

No: let $\nu$ be counting measure on $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$, and define
$$ \mu=\nu-\delta_{\sqrt{2}}$$

Then $\mu(O)\geq 0$ for any open subset $O$ of $\mathbb{R}$, but $\mu(\{\sqrt{2}\})=-1<0$.